# segmentation fault core dumped c

Tags: c

I'm new to C, I got an error today which is:

```
segmentation fault core dumped
```

I used gdb to track the code, I found that the error occurs in this line:

```
if (!strcmp(user_pass, passwddata->passwd))
```

Where `user_pass` is a **char array**, and `passwddata` is a **struct**, `passwd` is a member of the struct, which is also a type of **char array**, I tried to change the code to

```
if (!strcmp(user_pass, "ttt"))
```

The error didn't occur, so I guess the error occurs on that struct, if more code is needed, I can add it, here I want to understand under what condition can such kind of error occur on a struct?

Here is the code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

mypwent *passwddata; /* this has to be redefined in step 2 */
/* see pwent.h */

char important[LENGTH] = "***IMPORTANT***";

char user[LENGTH];
//char   *c_pass; //you might want to use this variable later...
char prompt[] = "password: ";
char *user_pass;

sighandler();

while (TRUE) {
    /* check what important variable contains - do not remove, part of buffer overflow test */
    printf("Value of variable 'important' before input of login name: %s\n",
            important);

    printf("login: ");
    fflush(NULL); /* Flush all  output buffers */
    __fpurge(stdin); /* Purge any data in stdin buffer */

    if (gets(user) == NULL) /* gets() is vulnerable to buffer */
    {
        exit(0); /*  overflow attacks.  */  
    }   
    printf("******************* %s\n",user);

    /* check to see if important variable is intact after input of login name - do not remove */
    printf("Value of variable 'important' after input of login name: %*.*s\n",
            LENGTH - 1, LENGTH - 1, important);

    user_pass = getpass(prompt);
    passwddata = getpwnam(user);

    printf("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ %s\n", user_pass);

    if (passwddata != NULL) {
        /* You have to encrypt user_pass for this to work */
        /* Don't forget to include the salt */


        if (!strcmp(user_pass, "ttt")) {

            printf(" You're in !\n");

            /*  check UID, see setuid(2) */
            /*  start a shell, use execve(2) */

        }
    }
    printf("Login Incorrect \n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Either `passwddata` or `passwd` are invalid.

Comment: Please add the code for how user_pass and passwddata are created. I suspect you didn't instantiate the pointer to passwddata

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely `passwd` or `passwddata` is `NULL`, in the latter case the `->` is attempting to deference the `NULL` pointer and thus it's crashing.

By changing your code to:

```
if (!strcmp(user_pass, "ttt"))
```

You isolated the first part, so you know `user_pass` is OK. You can use a debugger or some checks and printf's to get the values of `passwddata` and `passwd` to close on what the problem is.

---

Now that you've updated the code you know the problem is with `passwd`. You start with an empty pointer:

```
mypwent *passwddata;
```

Later you set the pointer to the return of `getpwnam`, presumably this is a pointer to a structure of type mypwent that you allocated some memory for:

```
passwddata = getpwnam(user);
```

You have a check to make sure `passwddata` isn't null:

```
if (passwddata != NULL) {
    if (!strcmp(user_pass, "ttt")) {
```

So now you've checked everything except `passwd`, passing a `null` into `strcmp()` will cause it to crash with that message, so I'm guessing you only allocated memory for the structure and not for the `char` array within the structure.

Comment: I think the problem is 'passwd' is 'NULL', by the way, what do you mean by 'deference the NULL pointer'?

Comment: @Zhenxiao - Your check for `if (passwddata != NULL)` will protect you from that. Basically if `getpwnam()` failed to allocate memory for your pointer the `->` operation would crash... but like I said, that's not the problem based on your code update. It must be `passwd`

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that `passwddata` is NULL.

Or the buffer `passwddata->passwd` points to

- shorter than the string in `user_pass`

and

- not null-terminated

Together those two make strcmp access beyond the limits of the second argument's buffer and hence cause the error.